# Scroll horizontally UIScrollView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I know this issue isn't new and there are many similar questions like this on this site. I've checked most of them but cannot find the answer.
I have a UITableView. Inside each UITableViewCell, I insert some of subviews (same level). One of subviews is a UIScrollView that I use to add some UIIMageView to scroll horizontally. The ScrollView is the bottom subviews (other subviews are above this ScrollView). I've made a test project and pushed to GitHub: https://github.com/lenhhoxung86/PageControlDemo.
The project works file and I noticed that delegate method: 
 `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is not called but it's just fine.

 However, when I moved this code into my real project, it doesn't work and the delegate method of tableview (didselectRowAtIndexPath) is actually called.

 Can anybody help me fix this? I'm going to insane for this issue. Following is picture captured on my test project[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the cause. In my test project, I used a Xib file created when I created a custom class of UITableViewCell. The view object is kind of class UITableViewCell by default. In my real project, I created custom class UITableViewCell first then created many Xib files so that I can load them when I need. By default, these View objects in these Xib files are kind of UIView. I re-created Xib file that belongs to class UITableView by default then it works. I have no idea how to convert existed Xib file with object of UIView type to UITableView.